# numpy bincount with class property

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of objects which all have a property that is an array, now i want to count how much occurances there are of each array length, can this be achieved with numpy.bincount? Can you give a key to bincount for example?

Comment: How about [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)? Create a histogram of over all array lengths. Unless further specification, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.histogram([len(obj.attrib) for obj in objects])
```

This is probably your best bet ! This is how I usually do it in such a scenario. I'm curious if anyone has a faster one